# Ansible lineinfile module removes space at the begining in the file

Tags: regex, ansible

I've found many similar questions here about `lineinfile` module, but none gives the solution to my problem.
I'm trying to add elasticsearch hosts in a `metricbeat` YAML configuration file.

The file contains this section :

```
 # Configure what output to use when sending the data collected by the beat.
 
 #-------------------------- Elasticsearch output ------------------------------
 output.elasticsearch:
   # Array of hosts to connect to.
 
   hosts: ["**ELASTICHOSTS**"]
```

The ansible code statement I wrote to insert host ip is :

```
 - name: Customize  metricbeat.yml hosts for PROD
   lineinfile:
     path: /etc/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml
     regexp: 'hosts:'
     line: "hosts: Db.es-dev.com:9200"
```

I was expecting the file to render like this :

```
 # Configure what output to use when sending the data collected by the beat.
 
 #-------------------------- Elasticsearch output ------------------------------
 output.elasticsearch:
   # Array of hosts to connect to.
 
   hosts: Db.es-dev.com:9200
```

But the above code removes the space before `hosts` and renders like this :

```
 # Configure what output to use when sending the data collected by the beat.
 
 #-------------------------- Elasticsearch output ------------------------------
 output.elasticsearch:
   # Array of hosts to connect to.
 
 hosts: ["**ELASTICHOSTS**"]
```

even using `regexp: '\s*hosts:'` or `regexp: '^\s*hosts:'` didn't give me the expected result.

To keep the trailing spaces I played on the line itself using this code :

```
 - name: Customize  metricbeat.yml hosts for PROD
   lineinfile:
     path: /etc/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml
     regexp: 'hosts:'
     line: "  hosts: Db.es-dev.com:9200"
```

Is there a better and/or an elegant way to keep these trailing spaces at the beginning of the file using the `regexp` attribute instead of forcing the spaces in the `line` attribute like I did above?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 - name: Customize  metricbeat.yml hosts for PROD
   replace:
     path: /etc/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml
     regexp: '^(\s*)hosts:.*'
     replace:'\1hosts: Db.es-dev.com:9200'
     backrefs: yes
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/83WlK2/1).

**EXPRESSION EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  hosts:                   'hosts:'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```

Comment: To explain a bit more: The `regexp` parameter only tells lineinfile which line to replace. It then replaces the complete line with the content of the `line` parameter. The `backrefs` parameter exists in the lineinfile module, too, so you can use it as shown in the answer, too.